# Create a find text function using webkitbrowser

Tags: c#

I'm trying to implement a find and highlight function using webkitbrowser (instead of default c# webbrowser).

Basically I need to do something like the Ctrl + F functionality.

I had something working in default webbrowser (example below), but this doesn't work in webKitBrowser.

```
IHTMLDocument2 doc = (IHTMLDocument2)this.webBrowser1.Document;
IHTMLSelectionObject sel = (IHTMLSelectionObject)doc.selection;
sel.empty();
IHTMLTxtRange rng = (IHTMLTxtRange)sel.createRange();

if (rng.findText(text, 1000000000, 0))
{
    rng.select();
    return true;
}

return false;
```

Thanks all in advance!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!
Probably it's duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9407758/finding-the-text-and-highlighting-the-same-with-in-ihtmlelement-in-webbrowser-co

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the quick turn around.
The issue you mentioned uses the default webBowser, I need this done by using the webKitBowser instead. :( :( :(